# Maximum Vertex Set With a Minimum Pairwise Distance Requirement in Directed Acyclic Graphs

Tags: graphs, np-complete, dynamic-programming, dag

Let $G=(V,E)$ be an unweighted directed acyclic graph with a set $V$ of vertices and a set $E$ of edges. The all-pairs shortest path problem can be solved efficiently using the Floyd-Warshall algorithm. The new objective is to find a subset of maximum cardinality $S \subseteq V$ such that for every pair of vertices $v$ and $u$ in $S$, the length of the shortest path from $v$  to $u$, if it exists, is greater than or equal to a positive natural number $k$.

This problem could be stated as a bottleneck capacity maximization problem in a complete directed weighted graph. You are given a complete weighted directed network and the objective is to find an induced subgraph with $m$ vertices where the minimum arc capacity is greater than or equal to $k$.

The reduction gives the arc from $v$ to $u$ a weight equal to the shortest path computed by Floyd-Warshall from $v$ to $u$ (if there is no path, a weight of $\infty$ is given). Is there an efficient/polynomial time dynamic programming approach to solve the problem?

Comment: Related: http://www.nakano-lab.cs.gunma-u.ac.jp/Papers/Max-Min_3-dispersion.pdf, https://towardsdatascience.com/the-facility-dispersion-problem-mixed-integer-programming-models-98ffdb56cd26

Comment: @NealYoung I hadn't considered that special case, I've modified the post. On a side note, would the undirected complete weighted graph problem also exhibit the same complexity?

Comment: My answer below was originally for the undirected weighted case.  In that case essentially the same reduction from Max Independent Set shows hardness of approximation.  However there is a bicriteria approximation (see Lemma 2 there).

Comment: @NealYoung  I see, that's right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*[EDIT: updated answer to apply to directed acyclic graphs.]*

**Lemma 1.** *This problem is equivalent, under approximation-preserving poly-time reductions, to Maximum Independent Set in undirected graphs.*

Independent Set is NP-complete and NP-hard to approximate within a factor of $n^{1-\epsilon}$ (for any $\epsilon>0$), so so is this problem:

**Corollary 1.** *The problem is NP-complete and NP-hard to approximate within a factor of $n^{1-\epsilon}$ for any $\epsilon>0.$*

---

*Proof of Lemma 1.* First we describe the reduction *from* Max Independent Set.  Given an instance $G=(V, E)$ of Max Independent Set, the reduction outputs the directed graph $G'$ obtained from $G$ by directing each edge so that $G'$ is acyclic
(e.g. arbitrarily order the vertices, then orient $(u, v)$ from $u$ to $v$ if $u$ comes before $v$ in the ordering),
and take the "distance budget" $k$ to be $2$.

To see that the reduction is correct,
note that a given vertex subset $S$
is an independent set in $G$
iff no two vertices in $S$ share an edge,
which holds iff no two vertices in $S$ are at distance 1 in $G'$.

Next we describe the reduction *to* Max Independent Set.
Given an instance $(G=(V, E), k)$ of OP's problem,
construct the undirected graph $G'=(V, E')$
where $E'= \{\{u, w\} \subseteq V : d(u, w) < k\}$.
Then a vertex subset $S$ is an independent set in $G'$
iff it contains no two vertices of distance less than $k$ in $G$.
$~~~\Box$

---

For the variant in undirected graphs,
there is a bicriteria approximation algorithm:

**Lemma 2.** *For the variant with undirected graphs,
in poly time one can compute a set $S_k$ achieving minimum distance $k$, with size at least the maximum size of any set $S^*_{2k}$ achieving distance at least $2k$.*

*Proof of Lemma 2.*
The algorithm is greedy: choose any vertex to add to $S_k$, delete all vertices within distance strictly less than $k$ from the vertex, and repeat until the graph is empty.

Each "ball" of deleted vertices contains at most one vertex from $S^*_{2k}$, so $|S_k| \ge |S^*_{2k}|$. $~~~~\Box$

For OP's problem, with *directed acyclic* graphs,
the greedy algorithm in Lemma 2 doesn't guarantee
such a good bicriteria approximation.

Comment: Thank you for your insightful answer! The reduction you gave is partly correct, the resulting graph isn't necessarily a directed acyclic graph.

Comment: Oops, I missed that. I've updated the hardness result in the answer.